# Refresh not working after deployment but works in local environment

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom`. After deployment the app is not working if we refresh the app, throwing an error `Not found`, but it works fine in the local environment. This happens for every route.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" exact element= {<Navigate to="/posts" />} />
  <Route path="/posts" exact element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/posts/search" exact element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/posts/:id" element={<PostDetails />} />
  <Route path="/auth" exact element={<Auth />} />
</Routes>
```

What went wrong and how to fix this. Is it not working because of improper use of `react-router-dom`?

Here is the deployed app link: [Memories-app](https://memories-b4a6.onrender.com/)

Comment: Where & how did you host the app? If you have hosted as static build you will need to add redirection to the root URL

Comment: Its a Render static side

Answer (score 1):

This error will occur wherever you would try to hit any route separately. The reason behind this is that render looks for file `/posts` which is not present.
For your case, you may resolve it by adding redirect/rewrite rules as below:
[image: setting up rules]

Answer (score 0):

Because react-router-dom only maintain clientside routing and not maintain a serverside routing that's why you need to rewrite your all path to index.html .
Seems like you hosted on render. Here is their doc how to rewrite path: https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app#using-client-side-routing

> If you use Reach Router or React Router for client-side routing, you will need to direct all routing requests to index.html so they can be handled by your routing library.
>
> You can do this easily by defining a Rewrite Rule for your static
> site. Go to the Redirects/Rewrites tab for your service and add a rule
> with the following values:
>
> Source Path   /*
>
> Destination Path  /index.html
>
> Action    Rewrite

Comment: But this doesn't solve the issue. After following the above steps, in every route if we refresh it redirects to `home/index.html`

Comment: can you share your project folder structure? where you have put your index.html file?

Comment: \client\public\index.html

Comment: So point to  that html in destination path.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm new bee here. What exactly are you trying to explain?

Answer (score 0):

The same happens to me when I used to host my React application. I used to make **_redirects** file in the same directory as index.html inside the public folder. And paste the below code:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

This works for me.

Comment: This simply redirects to `home/index.html` in every route. even if we're in `/posts/...` if we refresh our page it redirects to `home/index.html`. this might not be the correct fix.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
<Routes>
        <Route path='*' element={<Navigate replace to='/posts' />} />
        <Route path='/posts' element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path='/posts/search' element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path='/posts/:id' element={<PostDetails />} />
        <Route path='/auth' element={<Auth />} />
    </Routes>
```